# Balancing calls inside of a EditorWindow OnGUI method causing problems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm making a system to balance calls inside of the OnGUI method of a EditorWindow.
I'm doing the following:

```cs
        public void Update()
        {
            Repaint();
        }
```

Inside of my OnGUI method I'm calling this Balancer. I have one list with the callbacks (List).
So the idea is simple, some callvaxc
I'm skipping some repaint frames for the callback that has the complete GUI, and calling on each repaint for other callbacks (for example, a marquee label or dispalying gifs).

By some reason, this error happens "Getting control 0's position in a group with only 0 controls when doing repaint"

```cs
        private int m_repaintCounter;

        public void Draw()
        {
            Event e = Event.current;
            try
            {
                foreach (var action in m_actions)
                {
                    try
                    {

                            // Test 1
                            // MainAction is a class that inherits from Action (class MainAction : Action)
                            if (action is MainAction)
                            {
                                bool isDesignedType = e.rawType == EventType.Repaint || e.rawType == EventType.Layout;

                                if (isDesignedType)
                                    ++m_repaintCounter;

                                if (!(m_repaintCounter == 20 && isDesignedType))
                                    continue;
                                else
                                    m_repaintCounter = 0;
                            }

                            // Test 2
                            action.Value();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.LogException(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Due to recompile the collection will modified, so we need to avoid the exception
            }
        }
```

But if I comment the "Test 1" everythings works fine.

On the `ctor` of the class we need to specify a callback to a GUI method, for example:

```cs
        public Balancer(Action drawAction)
        {
            m_actions = new List<Action>();
            m_actions.Add(drawAction);
        }
```

So we could do easily (inside the `EditorWindow`):

```cs
    private Balancer m_balancer;

    public void OnEnable() 
    {
        m_balancer = new Balancer(Draw);
    }

    public void Draw() 
    {
        // This block will be called every 20 repaints as specified on the if statment
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal("box");
        {
            GUILayout.Button("I'm the first button");
            GUILayout.Button("I'm to the right");

            // This marquee will be called on each repaint
            m_balancer.AddAction(() => CustomClass.DisplayMarquee("example"));
        }
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
```

```cs
// Inside of the Balancer class we have
// We use System.Linq.Expressions to identify actions that were added already

private HashSet<string> m_alreadyAddedActions = new HashSet<string>();

public void AddAction(Expression<Action> callback) 
{
    if(!m_alreadyAddedActions.Add(callback.ToString()))
        return;

    m_actions.Add(callback.Compile());
}
```

I can't figure this out. I couldn't find any information on the internet. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ok, so, `OnGui` (IMGui) is awful to work with. If you aren't using it for an editor script, use the new 4.6 UI (UGui) instead.

Now then. The problem.

OnGui is called *at least* [twice every frame](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ongui-problem-firing-twice-a-time-solved.55459/#post-353780). One of those is to calculate layouts and the other is to actually draw stuff ("repaint").

*If the number of things, size of things, or anything else changes between these two calls* then Unity will error with "Getting control 0's position in a group with only 0 controls when doing repaint."

That is: you cannot change UI state in the IMGui system *at any point* after [Layout](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventType.Layout.html) and before [Repaint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventType.Repaint.html).

Only, only, ***only*** change state (and thereby which objects are being drawn) during `Event.current == EventType.Repaint` and only, only, ***only*** change state for the next frame (alternatively, do the changes during `Event.current == EventType.Layout`, provided that this same, new state will result in the same code path during Repaint). Do not, under any circumstances, make changes during Repaint that were not present during the previous Layout.

Comment: I have read this before. I know why this is caused... The problem is worse than changing "*number of things, size of things, or anything else*", because I'm not doing such thing... The problem is clear, if I comment the "Test 1" block, so only "action.Value();" is called, everything works fine... So I don't know what is happening exactly here.

Comment: `continue;` results in `action.Value()` not being called. This depends on `m_repaintCounter` and `isDesignedType`. Lets assume the counter is 0 and we call once for Layout. `isDesignedType` is true, which increments `m_repaintCounter`. As `m_repaintCounter != 20`, `continue` is called. This will repeat in pairs (odds are Layout, evens are Repaint). So when `m_repaintCounter` gets incremented to 19 (Layout), `continue` is called. When `m_repaintCounter` gets incremented to 20 (the following Repaint), `continue` is *not* called.

Comment: When `action.Value()` *is* called on this 20th iteration, it calls a function `Draw()` that invokes `GuiLayout` to add some stuff to the GUI. These were not present during the previous Layout (the 19th iteration): now there's a problem. Your state depended on a value that changed between Layout and Repaint.

Comment: Now I understand it. So I need to wait to Repaint to get called when Layout is reached. Thanks! Let me test it.

Comment: Layout and the following Repaint must always do the same thing. Its an annoying, frustrating, unforgiving system to work with. And sometimes you just want to swap from "this set of controls" to "that set of controls" and the thing that causes it to switch isn't based on user input. And you just have to accept that you have to skip the state change and wait for the next pass. I've written dozens and dozens of `if(Event.current != Layout) { skip! } else { change_state() }` or similar.